# Automatic network condition change for MacOS app manual testing

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, tools, test-strategy, desktop-application

I'm testing `MacOS app` and it relies a lot on the `network condition`, because it is uploading a lot of files.

I would like to simulate a network condition on my `macbook`, that automatically changes to simulate network condition in the wild, train, forest etc.

How could I do that?

I was thinking of pf, but not sure if a script can be set up to automatically `change speed`, `packet loss` every X seconds for let's say 15 minutes (depending on how many files are being uploaded by that app).

Comment: Similar questions from other SEs - https://superuser.com/questions/126642/throttle-network-bandwidth-per-application-in-mac-os-x & https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7426/bandwidth-shaper-or-bandwidth-controller-application-for-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a stubbed version of your clients objects that simulate some behavior. Then in the tests you inject this stubbed client.

```
interface Client {

   callTheNetwork();

}

class RealClient {

   callTheNetwork() { return http.call(); }

}

class SlowClient {

   callTheNetwork() {
     waitSeconds(3); 
     return stubbedResponse; 
   }
}
```